# C# Objects (Creating and Using)

Tags: c#, button, scope, out

In C# if you create an object on a button click, at the end of the click event, the object is no longer in scope. How do I create an object on the click of a button, but release it on the click of another button. Here is what I am trying to do:

Build an application that accepts user data and adds it to a database. The application contains two classes: Personal information and employer information. The personal information class object should be created when the "Start Application" button is pressed. The application then opens a tab that requests personal information. If the "Add Employer" button is selected, an instance of Employer is created. After they press submit at the end, it should close the one or two objects and return to the main menu. When the next person presses the button, it should go through the process again.

I can create objects on click or in the class itself, but how do you limit the life of the object between to button presses?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to add a field in your class.

Comment: if personalinfo has a property (or field) called employer, you can just set that data when the second button is clicked.

Comment: FYI "objects" are not "in scope" or "out of scope". "Scope" is a purely compile-time property; the *scope* of a named entity is *the region of program text in which that entity can be referred to by that name*. Your question is actually about *lifetime*, which is related to scope insofar as the lifetime of an object whose last reference is held in a local variable is either longer than, shorter than, or equal to the scope of that variable. If you are reading carefully and are wondering if I just said that scope and lifetime are effectively unrelated, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class-scoped data member. Very quick example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Foo foo;

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.foo = new Foo();
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I can access this.foo here. I can also dispose of it
        // if it is IDisposable and/or I can set it to null.
        // To check if button 1 was pressed, check to see if the object
        // is null (if it is, button 1 wasn't pressed)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by defining one of the event handlers anonymously inside of the other event handler:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Foo data = new Foo();
    EventHandler handler = null;
    handler = (s, args) =>
    {
        //Use Foo here
        DoStuff(data);
        button2.Click -= handler;
    };
    button2.Click += handler;
}
```

Note that we need to do some extra work to make sure to remove the event handler when it is clicked here.  If you don't need to do that, then it does simplify the code.

Here the anonymous method is closing over the local variable, which will extend that variable's lifetime for the lifetime of the anonymous method.  This approach, unlike those using a field, actually creates a variable who's lifetime lasts until the next button is clicked, and doesn't leave a variable lying around with a meaningless value before the first button is clicked or after the second is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're wanting to use properties?

Here's a link to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), but there's lots out there if you just Google'C# properties'

Answer (score 0):

> I can create objects on click or in the class itself, but how do you limit the life of the object between to button presses?

Sadly you're pretty much stuck with putting it at class scope. There is no simply way to limit the scope of an object to just a few methods within a class. If your 2 event handlers can access your Employer, then so can every other method within the class. You just have to not use it.

However, out of curiosity I managed to hack around and produce the effect you want. I did a class with 2 event handlers, one for each button, as well as a private Employer variable.

```
public class ButtonHandler
{
    private Employer employerData;

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        employerData = "set data here";
    }

    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        employerData = "use / clear data here";
    }
}
```

Then I went to my Form.Designer.cs and manually changed the button.Click event handler from the default `this.btnLoadPlaylist_Click` to my functions within the ButtonHandler class above. The problem with this is it gets deleted every time the Designer.CS is regenerated by Visual Studio. So the effect is possible, just not convenient with the tools we are given.

Comment: If you didnt put this in the designer.cs file, and changed your handlers to point to this class, it would not be blown away when the designer gets reset.

Comment: `"There is no simply way to limit the scope of an object to just a few methods within a class."` [Oh really.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21007557/1159478)